# Unexpected T_FOREACH

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo this Foreach, and I'm not sure on the correct way to do this. I've tried making a variable inside of the foreach and echoing that, but that'll only echo the last value of the array. Please show me the correct way to do this:

Comment: What are you trying to do with last line -> . "", "glows");

Comment: Whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: @tiGer Unexpected T_FOREACH, as stated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `implode` instead generating a string like that.

```
$glowVar = implode(',', $glows);
$client->sendMsgSpecial("Glows Updated", "Your glows have succesfully been updated. The following have been updated: " . $glowVar . ", "glows");
```

Or if want try your way then -

```
$str = '';
foreach($glows as $value) {
    $str .= $value . ', ';
}
$client->sendMsgSpecial("Glows Updated", "Your glows have succesfully been updated. The following have been updated: " . $str . ", "glows");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not echo to a method call. Use a variable.

```
$message = "Your glows have succesfully been updated. The following have been updated: ";
foreach($glows as $value) {
    $message .= $value . ', ';
}
```

And then call your method with variable.

```
$client->sendMsgSpecial("Glows Updated", $message, "glows");
```

Short answer but hope it helps.